# MVC4 Registering a user with extra details

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginer in MVC.
What i want is that, a user wil have a Location.
I want to keep all locations in a seprate table.

The models i came up with are:

Location Model:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

userprofile Model:

```
 public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Location location { get; set; }

}
```

Register Model:

```
 public class RegisterModel
{
//Attributes for UserName , password and ConfirmPassword
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Register Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {

                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, propertyValues: new { Location = new Location () , Name = model.Name });
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now when i try to register,

**Error : No mapping exists from object type HireCar2.Models.Location to a known managed provider native type.**

I have been trying on this Since noon.
Can i know what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: It looks like you're using Entity Framework. If so, have you set up your mapping with Location? With the Foreign Key between User and Location? You don't have a Location ID property on your User object.

Comment: isnt `public virtual Location Location { get; set; }` in UserProfile enough to set forigen key to Location ?
do we always have to give,`public int LocationId {get; set;}` and set it as the forigen key.?
and..
i tried changing that ..
gives Me the same error.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I haven't done a project allowing EF to do the convention table creation, and had forgotten that part.